# Unrecognized expression '$last' in node express project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Unrecognized expression '$last' in node express project i'm getting this error this $last in $project project section in activity section  `activity: { "$last": "$activity" }`

```
let newsFeed = await RecentActivity.aggregate([
            { $unwind: '$activity' },
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        { "activity_type": { $in: showActivityIds } },
                        { "activity_type": { $nin: activityIds } },
                        { "activity.activity_type": { $nin: notInSubActivity } },
                        { "activity.hide_by_admin" : 0}
                    ]
                }
            },
            { $match: { "activity.visible_to": 0 } },

            { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "activity.user", foreignField: "_id", as: "activity.user" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$activity.user", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "properties", localField: "activity.property", foreignField: "_id", as: "activity.property" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$activity.property", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "activity.target_user", foreignField: "_id", as: "activity.target_user" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$activity.target_user", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "activity.original_user", foreignField: "_id", as: "activity.original_user" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$activity.original_user", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "reviews", localField: "activity.review", foreignField: "_id", as: "activity.review" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$activity.review", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "activity.review.user", foreignField: "_id", as: "activity.review.user" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$activity.review.user", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "productorders", localField: "activity.productreview", foreignField: "_id", as: "activity.productreview" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$activity.productreview", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "activity.productreview.user", foreignField: "_id", as: "activity.productreview.user" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$activity.productreview.user", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "products", localField: "product", foreignField: "_id", as: "product" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$product", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "properties", localField: "property", foreignField: "_id", as: "property" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$property", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "posts", localField: "post", foreignField: "_id", as: "post" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$post", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "sharesummaries", localField: "activity.post", foreignField: "post", as: "sharesummary" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$sharesummary", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "post.user", foreignField: "_id", as: "post.user" } },
            { $unwind: { path: "$post.user", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },

            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$_id",
                    activity_type: { "$first": "$activity_type" },
                    feeling: { "$first": "$feeling" },
                    created_date: { "$first": "$created_date" },
                    updated_date: { "$max": "$updated_date" },
                    activity_count: { "$first": "$activity_count" },
                    activity_tipped_count: { "$first": "$activity_tipped_count" },
                    activity_upvote_count: { "$first": "$activity_upvote_count" },
                    activity_comment_count: { "$first": "$activity_comment_count" },
                    activity: { $push: "$activity" },
                    product: { "$first": "$product" },
                    property: { "$first": "$property" },
                    shared_post: { "$first": "$sharesummary" },
                    post: { "$first": "$post" },
                    user: { "$first": "$post.user" },
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 1,
                    updated_date: 1,
                    feeling: 1,
                    created_date: 1,
                    activity_type: 1,
                    activityCount: { "$size": "$activity" },
                    activity_count: 1,
                    activity_tipped_count: 1,
                    activity_upvote_count: 1,
                    activity_comment_count: 1,
                    activity: { "$last": "$activity" },
                    product: 1,
                    property: 1,
                    shared_post: 1,
                    post: 1,
                    user: 1,
                    rss_delete : 1
                }
            },
            { $sort: { "updated_date": -1 } },
            { $facet: facetquery },

        ]).exec();
```

I'm stuck here thanks in advance

Comment: What is the version of your mongodb server? The $last operator will support from MongoDB 4.4 [see](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last-array-element/).

Comment: 14(!) `$lookup` in one aggregation pipeline, this look like a very poor database design. MongoDB NoSQL is not a relational RDBMS!

Comment: mongo version - "version": "5.0.4" [@turivishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal)

Comment: [@WernfriedDomscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit) It means a lot to me if you can explain more deeply

Comment: When you compare the number of collections in a NoSQL DB with number of tables in according SQL relational DBMS then typically in NoSQL the number is much lower. NoSQL databases are not optimized for joins, some of them even do not support joins at all.